# Topology Verifying Hausdorff Property Problem

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Need some hints on this question because I don't know how to prove it:

On $X = [-1,1]$ we consider the topology $\tau$ that has the family $A = \{{[-1, b): b> 0}\} \cup \{{(a, 1] : a <0}\}$ as subbase.

1. Does $(X, T)$ verify the Hausdorff property?
2. Find the limit of ${x_n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

All help is welcome

Answer (score 2):

Well, every neighbourhood of $-1$ intersects every neighbourhood of $1$ ($0$ is always in both). This answers 1 as one counterexample pair suffices.

It's quite easy to check that $x_n \to -1$ and $x_n \to 1$ by the definitions.
So "the" limit is (on purpose) misleading. Even $x_n \to 0$ is true, I think.

Comment: I think it converges to every number as every neighborhood of any element contains $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Quite true, even worse.